# Magento: Last viewed products only shown parent categories

Tags: xml, magento, catalog, magento-1.7

we made a wine webshop: http://www.christianwinecellars.com/nl/assortiment/
And the problem is that the last viewed products only appears in the right column at categories which have subcategories. 
So when you view a product, then this appears at /assortiment/  en at France.

This is how it's done in local.xml

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <update handle="page_two_columns_left" />

    <reference name="right">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>right.reports.product.viewed</name></action>
    </reference>

    <reference name="left">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>currency</name></action>
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.leftnav</name></action>
        <block type="catalog/layer_view" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
        <block type="reports/product_viewed" name="right.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't appear at every category? Al categories are layered ( is anchor ).

Comment: `<reference name="right">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>right.reports.product.viewed</name></action>
    </reference>` - why did you added this?

Comment: Maybe that is superfluous because I don't have a right column. 
But unfortunately that is not the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you don't need to add/edit or remove any code.
Have you tried to set the page layout of your subcatagories
https://www.diigo.com/item/image/42c4x/vhg9

Answer (score 1):

I understand from the tags you are using Magento 1.7 ... According to: `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/reports.xml`

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <!-- Mage_Reports -->
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="reports/product_viewed" before="right.permanent.callout" name="right.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
            <block type="reports/product_compared" before="right.permanent.callout" name="right.reports.product.compared" template="reports/product_compared.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </default>

    <catalog_category_layered_nochildren translate="label">
        <label>Catalog Category (Without Subcategories)</label>
        <remove name="right.reports.product.viewed" />
        <reference name="right">
            <block type="reports/product_viewed" before="right.permanent.callout" name="left.reports.product.viewed" template="reports/product_viewed.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered_nochildren>
</layout>
```

So, there is `catalog_category_layered_nochildren` also.